# How to make simple visualization of continuously changing value in Android?

Tags: android, data-visualization

I want to visualize a continuously changing value (range 0-100) in my Android application. I implemented the following:

```
    ...

    voiceInput = (View) findViewById(R.id.voiceView);

    ...

    hUpdate = new Handler();
    rUpdate = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float ratio = getCurrentValue();//returns value between 0 and 100
            voiceInput.getLayoutParams().height = (int)ratio;
        }
    };

    tUpdate = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        while(true) {
          hUpdate.post(rUpdate);
          try {
            sleep(50);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
         }
        }
      };
    tUpdate.start();
```

View in xml:

```
<View
  android:id="@+id/voiceView"
  android:layout_width="15dp"
  android:layout_height="20dp"
  android:background="#FF0000" />
```

The problem is that the visible change of the view height is very slow (only once every ~2 seconds). My guess is that the update rate is too fast for setting the layout parameter of a view.

How else could I visualize the value with a bar or similar?

Comment: what is the getCurrentValue() doing?

Comment: it returns the value between 0 and 100

Comment: But how is that value calculated? Maybe that is what is slowing down the update rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: wrap your view in a `FrameLayout` with width=15dp, height=100dp. That should prevent layout from bubbling up.*

Starting from scratch I would recommend writing a custom view and varying the bar height in the `onDraw` method.

There is a second issue as well: you should multiply your height value by
`getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`. This is the equivalent, in code, of using density independent pixels in the XML file.

*Because the original code modifies layout parameters it may cause the whole activity to re-layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be use a `Timer`:
[Here](http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html) an example